# Customizing spacing between labels on x-axis using ng2-google-charts in Angular

Tags: angular, charts, google-visualization

I'm migrating some AngularJS code into modern Angular using ng2-google-charts and am running into an issue forcing a gap into the graph.

The application involves two google graphs - one that gives a line chart and overlaps another graph that gives an area chart.  My problem is that in the original AngularJS application there is a small gap between 1900 and 2015, but I'm not sure how to accomplish that in the new Angular code.  The configuration of the charts and data is the same in both versions.  The new version is using ng2-google-charts while the old version just used the Google Charts API directly, but that is the only difference.

**This is what the original one** looks like with the gap between 1900 and 2015 on the area chart so the line chart will fit between them.

[image]

**And this is what the new version looks like** - no gap and I'm not sure how to make one.  This is where I need help.

[image]

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { GoogleChartInterface } from 'ng2-google-charts/google-charts-interfaces';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'chart';

  public lineChart: GoogleChartInterface = {
    chartType: 'LineChart',
    dataTable:      [ ["Year", "Temp"],
          [1880,  0.54],
          [1881,  0.648],
          [1882,  0.648],
          [1883,  0.504],
          [1884,  0.396],
          [1885,  0.36],
          [1886,  0.396],
          [1887,  0.306],
          [1888,  0.486],
          [1889,  0.576],
          [1890,  0.18],
          [1891,  0.324],
          [1892,  0.216],
          [1893,  0.198],
          [1894,  0.27],
          [1895,  0.36],
          [1896,  0.612],
          [1897,  0.558],
          [1898,  0.306],
          [1899,  0.558],
          [1900,  0.648],
          [1901,  0.522],
          [1902,  0.324],
          [1903,  0.162],
          [1904,  0.018],
          [1905,  0.252],
          [1906,  0.396],
          [1907,  0.108],
          [1908,  0],
          [1909,  0.018],
          [1910,  0.108],
          [1911,  0],
          [1912,  0.198],
          [1913,  0.216],
          [1914,  0.54],
          [1915,  0.666],
          [1916,  0.27],
          [1917,  0.234],
          [1918,  0.414],
          [1919,  0.414],
          [1920,  0.414],
          [1921,  0.522],
          [1922,  0.378],
          [1923,  0.396],
          [1924,  0.342],
          [1925,  0.522],
          [1926,  0.666],
          [1927,  0.522],
          [1928,  0.468],
          [1929,  0.252],
          [1930,  0.612],
          [1931,  0.648],
          [1932,  0.576],
          [1933,  0.342],
          [1934,  0.594],
          [1935,  0.522],
          [1936,  0.576],
          [1937,  0.738],
          [1938,  0.72],
          [1939,  0.756],
          [1940,  0.936],
          [1941,  1.116],
          [1942,  1.044],
          [1943,  1.044],
          [1944,  1.296],
          [1945,  1.08],
          [1946,  0.756],
          [1947,  0.684],
          [1948,  0.684],
          [1949,  0.666],
          [1950,  0.486],
          [1951,  0.756],
          [1952,  0.81],
          [1953,  0.936],
          [1954,  0.558],
          [1955,  0.522],
          [1956,  0.414],
          [1957,  0.864],
          [1958,  0.972],
          [1959,  0.882],
          [1960,  0.81],
          [1961,  0.9],
          [1962,  0.936],
          [1963,  0.954],
          [1964,  0.504],
          [1965,  0.63],
          [1966,  0.72],
          [1967,  0.738],
          [1968,  0.72],
          [1969,  0.936],
          [1970,  0.828],
          [1971,  0.63],
          [1972,  0.81],
          [1973,  1.062],
          [1974,  0.63],
          [1975,  0.774],
          [1976,  0.63],
          [1977,  1.116],
          [1978,  0.972],
          [1979,  1.17],
          [1980,  1.242],
          [1981,  1.314],
          [1982,  1.098],
          [1983,  1.386],
          [1984,  1.026],
          [1985,  1.008],
          [1986,  1.17],
          [1987,  1.44],
          [1988,  1.44],
          [1989,  1.296],
          [1990,  1.548],
          [1991,  1.494],
          [1992,  1.224],
          [1993,  1.278],
          [1994,  1.368],
          [1995,  1.584],
          [1996,  1.35],
          [1997,  1.692],
          [1998,  1.908],
          [1999,  1.566],
          [2000,  1.53],
          [2001,  1.746],
          [2002,  1.854],
          [2003,  1.872],
          [2004,  1.8],
          [2005,  1.944],
          [2006,  1.872],
          [2007,  1.872],
          [2008,  1.746],
          [2009,  1.908],
          [2010,  2.034],
          [2011,  1.8],
          [2012,  1.89],
          [2013,  1.962],
          [2014,  2.106],
          [2015,  2.394]
        ],
    options: {
      x: {
        0: {
          side: 'top'
        }
      },
      height: 313,
      width:263,
      curveType: 'function',
      colors: ['#333'],
      legend: {
        position: 'none'
      },
      vAxis: {
        textPosition: 'none',
        gridlines: {
          color: 'transparent'
        },
        baselineColor: 'transparent'
      },
      hAxis: {
        format: 'none',
        textPosition: 'none',
        gridlines: {
          color: 'transparent'
        }
      },
      chartArea: {
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%"
      },
      backgroundColor: {
        fill: 'transparent'
      },
      enableInteractivity: false
    }
  };

    public areaChart: GoogleChartInterface = {
      chartType: 'AreaChart',
      dataTable: [
        ['Year', 'Baseline', 'Coal Power Plants', 'Natural Gas', 'Waste', 'Farming', 'Factories', 'Buildings', 'Houses', 'Ships', 'Planes', 'Cars & Trucks', 'temp'],
        ['1900', undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, 60.1],
        ['2015', 56.5, 0.55, 0.30, 0.13, 0.28, 0.28, 0.32, 0.19, 0.04, 0.05, 0.3, 60.1],
        ['2020', 56.5, 0.59, 0.32, 0.13, 0.3, 0.3, 0.34, 0.2, 0.04, 0.05, 0.33, 60.1],
        ['2030', 56.5, 0.71, 0.37, 0.15, 0.34, 0.35, 0.41, 0.24, 0.05, 0.05, 0.39, 60.1],
        ['2040', 56.5, 0.83, 0.43, 0.17, 0.39, 0.42, 0.48, 0.29, 0.06, 0.06, 0.46, 60.1],
        ['2050', 56.5, 0.98, 0.5, 0.19, 0.45, 0.49, 0.57, 0.34, 0.07, 0.07, 0.54, 60.1],
        ['2060', 56.5, 1.14, 0.57, 0.21, 0.5, 0.57, 0.66, 0.39, 0.08, 0.09, 0.63, 60.1],
        ['2070', 56.5, 1.31, 0.63, 0.23, 0.55, 0.66, 0.76, 0.45, 0.09, 0.1, 0.72, 60.1],
        ['2080', 56.5, 1.47, 0.69, 0.24, 0.59, 0.74, 0.85, 0.51, 0.1, 0.11, 0.81, 60.1],
        ['2090', 56.5, 1.63, 0.74, 0.25, 0.62, 0.82, 0.94, 0.56, 0.11, 0.12, 0.9, 60.1],
        ['2100', 56.5, 1.77, 0.79, 0.26, 0.66, 0.89, 1.03, 0.61, 0.12, 0.14, 0.98, 60.1]
      ],
      options: {

        isStacked: 'absolute',
        height: 690,
        width: 1340,
        areaOpacity: 0.5,
        legend: {
          position: 'none'
        },
        series: {
          11: {
            type: 'line',
            color: '#f23573',
            lineDashStyle: [2, 2]
          }
        },
        colors: ['#dcf8fa', '#b720dd', '#f6705a', '#f89b2d', '#fbcb0a', '#91d957', '#46d999', '#3cd6d8', '#60bcfd', '#96a6fb', '#4459c8', '#f23573'],
        vAxis: {
          minValue: 56.3,
          ticks: [57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64],
          format: '##.#',
          viewWindowMode: 'explicit',
          viewWindow: {
            max: 64,
            min: 56.3
          }
        },
        hAxis: {
          minValue: 1900,
          ticks: [1900, 2015, 2020, 2030, 2040, 2050, 2060, 2070, 2080, 2090, 2100],
          scaleType: 'linear'
        },
        chartArea: {
          left: 60,
          top: 40,
          width: "90%",
          height: "88%"
        },
        enableInteractivity: false
      }
    };


    constructor(){

    }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div  style="width:90%;height:700px;margin-left: 5.5em;margin-right: auto;margin-bottom: 3em;">
  <google-chart [data]="areaChart"></google-chart>
</div>
<div id="linechart_container">
  <google-chart [data]="lineChart" id="linechart_div"></google-chart>
</div>
```

**app.component.scss**

```
#linechart_container
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 263px;
    height: 620px;
    background-color: #DDD;
    opacity: 0.8;
    top:0px;
    padding:0;
    left: 156px;
    padding-top: 1em;
}
#linechart_div
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 263px;
    /*height:315px;*/
    /*top:380px;*/
    height: 313px;
    top: 382px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in similar fashion as the target line data row,
you could add a couple blank rows (`undefined`) to the data table to increase the gap.

```
  ['1900', undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, 60.1],
  [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined],
  [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined],
  ['2015', 56.5, 0.55, 0.30, 0.13, 0.28, 0.28, 0.32, 0.19, 0.04, 0.05, 0.3, 60.1],
```

then set the width of the chart and the background container to fill the gap.

```
// line chart width
options: {
  height: 313,
  width: 302,
  ...


/* background css */
#linechart_container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 302px;
  ...
```

see following working snippet...
(although not angular, works the same)

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['controls', 'corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var lineChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'LineChart',
    containerId: 'linechart_div',
    dataTable: google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ["Year", "Temp"],
      [1880,  0.54],
      [1881,  0.648],
      [1882,  0.648],
      [1883,  0.504],
      [1884,  0.396],
      [1885,  0.36],
      [1886,  0.396],
      [1887,  0.306],
      [1888,  0.486],
      [1889,  0.576],
      [1890,  0.18],
      [1891,  0.324],
      [1892,  0.216],
      [1893,  0.198],
      [1894,  0.27],
      [1895,  0.36],
      [1896,  0.612],
      [1897,  0.558],
      [1898,  0.306],
      [1899,  0.558],
      [1900,  0.648],
      [1901,  0.522],
      [1902,  0.324],
      [1903,  0.162],
      [1904,  0.018],
      [1905,  0.252],
      [1906,  0.396],
      [1907,  0.108],
      [1908,  0],
      [1909,  0.018],
      [1910,  0.108],
      [1911,  0],
      [1912,  0.198],
      [1913,  0.216],
      [1914,  0.54],
      [1915,  0.666],
      [1916,  0.27],
      [1917,  0.234],
      [1918,  0.414],
      [1919,  0.414],
      [1920,  0.414],
      [1921,  0.522],
      [1922,  0.378],
      [1923,  0.396],
      [1924,  0.342],
      [1925,  0.522],
      [1926,  0.666],
      [1927,  0.522],
      [1928,  0.468],
      [1929,  0.252],
      [1930,  0.612],
      [1931,  0.648],
      [1932,  0.576],
      [1933,  0.342],
      [1934,  0.594],
      [1935,  0.522],
      [1936,  0.576],
      [1937,  0.738],
      [1938,  0.72],
      [1939,  0.756],
      [1940,  0.936],
      [1941,  1.116],
      [1942,  1.044],
      [1943,  1.044],
      [1944,  1.296],
      [1945,  1.08],
      [1946,  0.756],
      [1947,  0.684],
      [1948,  0.684],
      [1949,  0.666],
      [1950,  0.486],
      [1951,  0.756],
      [1952,  0.81],
      [1953,  0.936],
      [1954,  0.558],
      [1955,  0.522],
      [1956,  0.414],
      [1957,  0.864],
      [1958,  0.972],
      [1959,  0.882],
      [1960,  0.81],
      [1961,  0.9],
      [1962,  0.936],
      [1963,  0.954],
      [1964,  0.504],
      [1965,  0.63],
      [1966,  0.72],
      [1967,  0.738],
      [1968,  0.72],
      [1969,  0.936],
      [1970,  0.828],
      [1971,  0.63],
      [1972,  0.81],
      [1973,  1.062],
      [1974,  0.63],
      [1975,  0.774],
      [1976,  0.63],
      [1977,  1.116],
      [1978,  0.972],
      [1979,  1.17],
      [1980,  1.242],
      [1981,  1.314],
      [1982,  1.098],
      [1983,  1.386],
      [1984,  1.026],
      [1985,  1.008],
      [1986,  1.17],
      [1987,  1.44],
      [1988,  1.44],
      [1989,  1.296],
      [1990,  1.548],
      [1991,  1.494],
      [1992,  1.224],
      [1993,  1.278],
      [1994,  1.368],
      [1995,  1.584],
      [1996,  1.35],
      [1997,  1.692],
      [1998,  1.908],
      [1999,  1.566],
      [2000,  1.53],
      [2001,  1.746],
      [2002,  1.854],
      [2003,  1.872],
      [2004,  1.8],
      [2005,  1.944],
      [2006,  1.872],
      [2007,  1.872],
      [2008,  1.746],
      [2009,  1.908],
      [2010,  2.034],
      [2011,  1.8],
      [2012,  1.89],
      [2013,  1.962],
      [2014,  2.106],
      [2015,  2.394]
    ]),
    options: {
      height: 313,
      width: 302,
      curveType: 'function',
      colors: ['#333'],
      legend: {
        position: 'none'
      },
      vAxis: {
        textPosition: 'none',
        gridlines: {
          color: 'transparent'
        },
        baselineColor: 'transparent'
      },
      hAxis: {
        format: 'none',
        textPosition: 'none',
        gridlines: {
          color: 'transparent'
        }
      },
      chartArea: {
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%'
      },
      backgroundColor: {
        fill: 'transparent'
      },
      enableInteractivity: false
    }
  });

  var areaChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    containerId: 'areachart_div',
    chartType: 'AreaChart',
    dataTable: google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Year', 'Baseline', 'Coal Power Plants', 'Natural Gas', 'Waste', 'Farming', 'Factories', 'Buildings', 'Houses', 'Ships', 'Planes', 'Cars & Trucks', 'temp'],
      ['1900', undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, 60.1],
      [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined],
      [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined],
      ['2015', 56.5, 0.55, 0.30, 0.13, 0.28, 0.28, 0.32, 0.19, 0.04, 0.05, 0.3, 60.1],
      ['2020', 56.5, 0.59, 0.32, 0.13, 0.3, 0.3, 0.34, 0.2, 0.04, 0.05, 0.33, 60.1],
      ['2030', 56.5, 0.71, 0.37, 0.15, 0.34, 0.35, 0.41, 0.24, 0.05, 0.05, 0.39, 60.1],
      ['2040', 56.5, 0.83, 0.43, 0.17, 0.39, 0.42, 0.48, 0.29, 0.06, 0.06, 0.46, 60.1],
      ['2050', 56.5, 0.98, 0.5, 0.19, 0.45, 0.49, 0.57, 0.34, 0.07, 0.07, 0.54, 60.1],
      ['2060', 56.5, 1.14, 0.57, 0.21, 0.5, 0.57, 0.66, 0.39, 0.08, 0.09, 0.63, 60.1],
      ['2070', 56.5, 1.31, 0.63, 0.23, 0.55, 0.66, 0.76, 0.45, 0.09, 0.1, 0.72, 60.1],
      ['2080', 56.5, 1.47, 0.69, 0.24, 0.59, 0.74, 0.85, 0.51, 0.1, 0.11, 0.81, 60.1],
      ['2090', 56.5, 1.63, 0.74, 0.25, 0.62, 0.82, 0.94, 0.56, 0.11, 0.12, 0.9, 60.1],
      ['2100', 56.5, 1.77, 0.79, 0.26, 0.66, 0.89, 1.03, 0.61, 0.12, 0.14, 0.98, 60.1]
    ]),
    options: {
      isStacked: 'absolute',
      height: 690,
      width: 1340,
      areaOpacity: 0.5,
      legend: {
        position: 'none'
      },
      series: {
        11: {
          type: 'line',
          color: '#f23573',
          lineDashStyle: [2, 2]
        }
      },
      colors: ['#dcf8fa', '#b720dd', '#f6705a', '#f89b2d', '#fbcb0a', '#91d957', '#46d999', '#3cd6d8', '#60bcfd', '#96a6fb', '#4459c8', '#f23573'],
      vAxis: {
        minValue: 56.3,
        ticks: [57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64],
        format: '##.#',
        viewWindowMode: 'explicit',
        viewWindow: {
          max: 64,
          min: 56.3
        }
      },
      chartArea: {
        left: 60,
        top: 40,
        width: '90%',
        height: '88%'
      },
      enableInteractivity: false
    }
  });

  lineChart.draw();
  areaChart.draw();
});
```

```css
#areachart_container {
  width: 90%;
  height: 700px;
  margin-left: 5.5em;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 3em;
}

#linechart_container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 302px;
  height: 620px;
  background-color: #DDD;
  opacity: 0.8;
  top:0px;
  padding:0;
  left: 156px;
  padding-top: 1em;
}

#linechart_div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 263px;
  /*height:315px;*/
  /*top:380px;*/
  height: 313px;
  top: 382px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="areachart_container">
  <div id="areachart_div"></div>
</div>
<div id="linechart_container">
  <div id="linechart_div"></div>
</div>
```

---

notes:

1) the following options you had on the `hAxis`,
have no effect on a discrete axis (string values --> `'1900', '2015', ...`),
and are only valid on a continuous axis (number, date, etc... --> `1900, 2015`)
see [discrete vs continuous axis](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes#Terminology)

```
    minValue: 1900,
    ticks: [1900, 2015, 2020, 2030, 2040, 2050, 2060, 2070, 2080, 2090, 2100],
    scaleType: 'linear'
```

2) recommend using css rather than the `style` attribute (on the area chart container)

see above snippet...